# Stephanus numbering

Tags: reference-request, plato

I have all of Plato's works, but unfortunately they're missing the Stephanus numbering. Is there a resource which I can use to see which paragraphs they refer to? A brief table containing the first few words would be good enough!

Answer (score 1):

This online website has a fairly exhaustive listing of online versions of [Plato's dialogues](http://plato-dialogues.org/links.htm). Most of the English translations will have the numbers listed, definitely the Perseus ones. This [site](http://beingsufficiently.blogspot.com/2011/03/public-domain-plato-with-stephanus.html) also discusses the same issue and provides more (though largely overlapping) suggestions.

If the dialogues you need are there, then hopefully that solves it. Otherwise I can point you to this [list](http://plato-dialogues.org/faq/faq007.htm) which at least tells you which dialogues are in which Stephanus number range.

Short of taking out my Complete Works of Plato and reading you the numbers to passages I think that might be the best I can do. Good luck!